# Bootstrap 3: Extending div outside container on right side

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a layout which needs a div to extend it outside the .container div only on the right side.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/krish7878/c5n365ek/1/

HTML Code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 left">
           Left Container
        </div><!-- /.col-6 -->
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 right">
            Right Container
        </div><!-- /.col-6 -->
    </div><!-- /.row -->
</div><!-- /.container -->
```

CSS Code:

```
.left{
    background-color: #999;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 30px 0px;
}
.right{
    background-color: #49c8ff;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 30px 0px;
}
```

I want the right container with blue background to extend on the right side fully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for? You just need to make the `.container` `width:100%` and you can add `padding-left`

```
.container{
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 120px; //whatever you want
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/c5n365ek/2/)